# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have error like this
Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int

controller

```
if ($this->input->post('nama') == 'pendek boju jeans') {
                    $a=0.810;
                }else{
                    $a=1.144;
                }
                $kain= $this->input->post('id_kain');
                $b=$this->jeans_model->luaskain($kain);
                $tpotongan=round($a/$b);
```

model

```
    public function luaskain($kain)
  {
    $this->db->select("ukuran");
    $this->db->from("bahankain");
    $this->db->where('id_kain',$kain);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row();
  }
```

in my model get value from bahankain.ukuran like this

```
|ukuran|
|800|
```

why error `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int`
and how to solve this?

Comment: what do you get on var_dump($b) ??

Comment: Because object is a structure with methods and properties and `int` is just a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what are the names in you script mean, but the problem is that object, as I said, is a structure with at least some properties and `int` is just a **number**.

So when you divide something by object - what does it means? What value from object should be taken? Who can tell? The same is true when you divide object by something.

So, I suppose, first you should `var_dump` or `print_r` your `$b` variable which is object, used in a division. And then - find out what number from `$b` variable you should use. I suppose it's a `ukuran` (whatever it means).

So, more precise code is:

```
$tpotongan = round($a / ($b->ukuran)); // taking ukuran property from object
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in model

```
public function luaskain($kain)
  {
    $this->db->select("ukuran");
    $this->db->from("bahankain");
    $this->db->where('id_kain',$kain);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result=$query->row();
        if (isset($result))
        {
            return $result->columnname;//write your column name
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$query->row()`, in your method `luaskain($kain)`, returns an object of type `stdClass`, that represents a *row* (one or more fields with values) from the result-set of a database query – *not* a single field value.

In order to access the value of a single field, in this case the field `ukuran`, you need to access it like `$b->ukuran`. You can use *that* value to divide with (but make sure it's non-zero, of course, because you cannot divide by zero).